How to add multiple photos/videos/audios into a single entry in TimelineJS?
I want to add multiple photos/audios/videos into a single slide in TimelineJS, but I don't know how? I downloaded the code from this github: https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS3, and I am trying to change it in VScode to allow me to accomplish my goal, but I don't know how to do it .
Will someone help me?
I don't know how to do any of it

Follow their guide here: https://timeline.knightlab.com/#make

Please click [edit], then the [<>] statcksnippet editor and create a [mcve]

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
